# A property of the distribution related to stochastic ordering

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics

Let $X$ be a random variable with a symmetric support $S\subset[-M,M]$ for some $M>0$. (i.e., if x is a point of increase of CDF $F_X(\cdot)$, so is $-x$.)

Has the infimum value of $c$ such that
\begin{equation} 
X\leq_1 -X+c
\end{equation}
been discussed in literature? Any non-trivial upper/lower bounds on $c$?

($A\leq_1B$ means that $B$ first order dominates $A$.)

Comment: Bounds (upper? lower? on $c$?) in what non-tautological terms? If $X$ is symmetric, then $c=0$. So, $c$ is a measure of asymmetry.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Yes, any upper/lower non-trivial bounds on $c$ since we already know  that it is non-negative and lower than 2 times maximum of the support. (I will edit the question accordingly.) Yes, I just wanted to know if this notion of asymmetry has been investigated before.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$Your stochastic domination condition $X\le_1-X+c$ can be written as
$$P(X>x)\le P(-X+c>x)\tag{1}\label{1}$$
for all real $x$.

If $c\ge2M$, then $X\le M\le2M-X\le-X+c$, so that $X\le-X+c$ and hence $X\le_1-X+c$.

On the other hand, if $c<2M$ and $P(X=M)=1$, then
$$P(X>c/2)=1\not\le0=P(X<c/2)=P(-X+c>c/2)$$
so that \eqref{1} does not hold for $x=c/2$ and hence it is not true that $X\le_1-X+c$.

(If you insist that the support of $X$ be the entire interval $[-M,M]$, just use an approximation. For instance, you can assume that $P(X\in B)=(1-\ep)\,1(M\in B)+\ep\dfrac{|B\cap[-M,M]|}{2M}$ for any $\ep\in(0,1/2]$ and all Borel subsets of $\Bbb R$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. Then the support of the distribution of $X$ will be the entire interval $[-M,M]$, whereas, for $c<2M$,
$$P(X>c/2)>P(X=M)=1-\ep\ge\frac12$$
and hence
$$P(-X+c>c/2)=P(X<c/2)=1-P(X>c/2)<\frac12,$$
so that
$P(X>c/2)>P(-X+c>c/2)$ and hence \eqref{1} does not hold for $x=c/2$. So, it is not true that $X\le_1-X+c$ if $c<2M$.)

So, the best lower bound on $c$ under the given conditions is $2M$. (There is no finite upper bound on $c$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151905/discussion-on-answer-by-iosif-pinelis-a-property-of-the-distribution-related-to); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.